# FBSDK Access token string is always nil

Tags: ios, django, swift, facebook, fbsdk

I am building an iOS app that uses facebook for user login and then will pass the token to my django web server to convert into a access token. The issue is that the FBSDK access token is appearing and can be used but is appearining as nil when trying to access the string value of it which can be seen in this function. I have been trying for hours to find the issue and so any sort of help would be much appreciated.

```
func login(userType: String, completionHandler: @escaping (NSError?) -> Void) {
        let path = "api/social/convert-token"
        let url = baseURL!.appendingPathComponent(path)
        let params: [String: Any] = [
            "grant_type": "convert-token",
            "client_id": CLIENT_ID,
            "client_secret": CLIENT_SECRET,
            "backend": "facebook",
            "token": FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString!,
            "user_type": userType
        ]
        /* Does appear */ print("THE TOKEN NO STRING IS \(FBSDKAccessToken.current()")
        /* Shows as nil */ print(" THE TOKEN IS \(FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString!)")

        Alamofire.request(url!, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding(), headers: nil).responseJSON { (response: DataResponse<Any>) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                let jsonData = JSON(value)
                self.accessToken = jsonData["access_token"].string!
                self.refreshToken = jsonData["refresh_token"].string!
                self.expired = Date().addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval(jsonData["expires_in"].int!))
                completionHandler(nil)
                break
            case .failure(let error):
                completionHandler(error as NSError?)
                break
            }
        }
    }
```